# how to integrate redux framework metabox into custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, redux-framework

I am using Redux Framework for theme development but I stuck on Metabox. I tried this doc https://docs.reduxframework.com/extensions/metaboxes/ but I didn't get any result.

I am unable to get the custom field on selected custom post type.

In `extentions-init.php`, I found:

```php
// All extensions placed within the extensions directory will be auto-loaded for your Redux instance.
Redux::setExtensions( $opt_name, dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/extensions/' );

// Any custom extension configs should be placed within the configs folder.
if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/configs/' ) ) {
    $files = glob( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/configs/*.php' );
    if ( ! empty( $files ) ) {
        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

It's clearly shows the custom metabox will be load from configs folder but it doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this... note that you need to add_action(

```
if ( !function_exists( "master_metaboxes_function" ) ){
    function master_metaboxes_function($master_metaboxes) {
    if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/configs/' ) ) {
        $files = glob( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/configs/*.php' );
    if ( ! empty( $files ) ) {foreach ( $files as $file ) {include $file;} }
    }
    return $master_metaboxes;
  }
    // note this has to load AFTER the action loads...
  add_action('redux/metaboxes/'.$YOUR_OPTION_ID.'/boxes', 'master_metaboxes_function'); 
}
```

Read this: https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/issues/2605

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation you need to hook into a filter to set your metaboxes, so in your plugin or theme, add this code :

*(don't forget to replace {$redux_opt_name} with your unique vendor prefix/opt_name to prevent colissions with other plugins)*

```
if ( !function_exists( "{%redux_opt_name%}_redux_add_metaboxes" ) ):
    function {%redux_opt_name%}_redux_add_metaboxes($metaboxes) {
        // Declare your sections
        $boxSections = array();
        $boxSections[] = array(
            //'title'         => __('General Settings', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            //'icon'          => 'el-icon-home', // Only used with metabox position normal or advanced
            'fields'        => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'sidebar',
                    //'title' => __( 'Sidebar', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                    'desc' => 'Please select the sidebar you would like to display on this page. Note: You must first create the sidebar under Appearance > Widgets.',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'data' => 'sidebars',
                ),
            ),
        );

        // Declare your metaboxes
        $metaboxes = array();
        $metaboxes[] = array(
            'id'            => 'sidebar',
            'title'         => __( 'Sidebar', 'fusion-framework' ),
            'post_types'    => array( 'page', 'post', 'acme_product' ),
            //'page_template' => array('page-test.php'), // Visibility of box based on page template selector
            //'post_format' => array('image'), // Visibility of box based on post format
            'position'      => 'side', // normal, advanced, side
            'priority'      => 'high', // high, core, default, low - Priorities of placement
            'sections'      => $boxSections,
        );

        return $metaboxes;
    }
    // Change {%redux_opt_name%} to your opt_name
    add_filter("redux/metaboxes/{%redux_opt_name%}/boxes", "redux_add_metaboxes");
endif;
```